# How can I make json data from requests into excel file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This is my first time dealing with json data. So I'm not that familiar with the structure of json.

I got some data through "we the people" e-petition sites with following code:

```
url = "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json?limit=3&offset=0&createdBefore=1573862400"
jdata_2 = requests.get(url).json()
```

Yet, I realize this is something different from... the ordinary json structure since I got some error while I tried to convert it into excel file with pandas

```
df = pandas.read_json(jdata_2)
```

Obviously, I must miss something which I must have done before using pandas.read_json() code.
I have searched for the answer but most of questions are "How can I convert json data into excel data", which needs json data. For my case, I scraped it from the url, so I thought I could make that strings into json data, and then try to convert it into excel data as well. So I tried to use json.dump() as well, but it didn't work as well.

I know it must be the naive question. But I'm not sure where I can start with this naive question. If anyone can instruct me how to deal with it, I would really appreciate it. Or link me some references that I can study as well.

Thank you for your help in advance.

### This is the json data with the requests, and I pprint it with indent=4.

Input:

```
url = "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json?limit=3&offset=0&createdBefore=1573862400"
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(jdata_2)
```

Output :

```
{   'metadata': {   'requestInfo': {   'apiVersion': 1,
                                   'query': {   'body': None,
                                                'createdAfter': None,
                                                'createdAt': None,
                                                'createdBefore': '1573862400',
                                                'isPublic': 1,
                                                'isSignable': None,
                                                'limit': '3',
                                                'mock': 0,
                                                'offset': '0',
                                                'petitionsDefaultLimit': '1000',
                                                'publicThreshold': 149,
                                                'responseId': None,
                                                'signatureCount': None,
                                                'signatureCountCeiling': None,
                                                'signatureCountFloor': 0,
                                                'signatureThreshold': None,
                                                'signatureThresholdCeiling': None,
                                                'signatureThresholdFloor': None,
                                                'sortBy': 'DATE_REACHED_PUBLIC',
                                                'sortOrder': 'ASC',
                                                'status': None,
                                                'title': None,
                                                'url': None,
                                                'websiteUrl': 'https://petitions.whitehouse.gov'},
                                   'resource': 'petitions'},
                'responseInfo': {   'developerMessage': 'OK',
                                    'errorCode': '',
                                    'moreInfo': '',
                                    'status': 200,
                                    'userMessage': ''},
                'resultset': {'count': 1852, 'limit': 3, 'offset': 0}},
'results': [   {   'body': 'Please save kurdish people in syria \r\n'
                           'pleaee save north syria',
                   'created': 1570630389,
                   'deadline': 1573225989,
                   'id': '2798897',
                   'isPublic': True,
                   'isSignable': False,
                   'issues': [   {   'id': 326,
                                     'name': 'Homeland Security &amp; '
                                             'Defense'}],
                   'petition_type': [   {   'id': 291,
                                            'name': 'Call on Congress to '
                                                    'act on an issue'}],
                   'reachedPublic': 0,
                   'response': [],
                   'signatureCount': 149,
                   'signatureThreshold': 100000,
                   'signaturesNeeded': 99851,
                   'status': 'closed',
                   'title': 'Please save rojava north syria\r\n'
                            'please save kurdish people\r\n'
                            'please stop erdogan\r\n'
                            'plaease please',
                   'type': 'petition',
                   'url': 'https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/please-save-rojava-north-syria-please-save-kurdish-people-please-stop-erdogan-plaease-please'},
               {   'body': 'Kane Friess was a 2 year old boy who was '
                           "murdered by his mom's boyfriend, Gyasi "
                           'Campbell. Even with expert statements from '
                           'forensic anthropologists, stating his injuries '
                           'wete the result of homicide. Mr. Campbell was '
                           'found guilty of involuntary manslaughter. This '
                           "is an outrage to Kane's Family and our "
                           'community.',
                   'created': 1566053365,
                   'deadline': 1568645365,
                   'id': '2782248',
                   'isPublic': True,
                   'isSignable': False,
                   'issues': [   {   'id': 321,
                                     'name': 'Criminal Justice Reform'}],
                   'petition_type': [   {   'id': 281,
                                            'name': 'Change an existing '
                                                    'Administration '
                                                    'policy'}],
                   'reachedPublic': 0,
                   'response': [],
                   'signatureCount': 149,
                   'signatureThreshold': 100000,
                   'signaturesNeeded': 99851,
                   'status': 'closed',
                   'title': "Kane's Law. Upon which the murder of a child, "
                            'regardless of circumstances, be seen as 1st '
                            'degree murder.  A Federal Law.',
                   'type': 'petition',
                   'url': 'https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/kanes-law-upon-which-murder-child-regardless-circumstances-be-seen-1st-degree-murder-federal-law'},
               {   'body': "Schumer and Pelosi's hatred and refusing to "
                           'work with President Donald J. Trump is holding '
                           'America hostage. We the people know securing '
                           'our southern border is a priority which will '
                           'not happen with these two in office. Lets '
                           'build the wall NOW!',
                   'created': 1547050064,
                   'deadline': 1549642064,
                   'id': '2722358',
                   'isPublic': True,
                   'isSignable': False,
                   'issues': [   {'id': 306, 'name': 'Budget &amp; Taxes'},
                                 {   'id': 326,
                                     'name': 'Homeland Security &amp; '
                                             'Defense'},
                                 {'id': 29, 'name': 'Immigration'}],
                   'petition_type': [   {   'id': 291,
                                            'name': 'Call on Congress to '
                                                    'act on an issue'}],
                   'reachedPublic': 0,
                   'response': [],
                   'signatureCount': 149,
                   'signatureThreshold': 100000,
                   'signaturesNeeded': 99851,
                   'status': 'closed',
                   'title': 'Remove Chuck Schumer and Nancy Pelosi from '
                            'office',
                   'type': 'petition',
                   'url': 'https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/remove-chuck-schumer-and-nancy-pelosi-office'}]}
```

And this is the Error message I got
Input :

```
df = pandas.read_json(jdata_2)
```

Output :

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: You didn't show the JSON that was causing the error and didn't specify what the error was. Both are elementary if you want others to help with your specific case. You say that you are not familiar with JSON (which is OK), and express wish to learn more (which is great), but then you ask for links to references... have you tried to just Google? it's not like it's some esoteric subject only a select few can identify the necessary resources for. It's JSON...

Comment: @obe Sorry for that obe. Actually I mentioned about the reference because, I thought it might be much easier to someone who can answer. I am also googling about json right now. I had no intention to be lazy worker. But since there are so much information about json, I'm dealing with from the scratch. So it would take a while. Sorry again if that might be offensive.

And I edited the json and the error. I forgot to attach it. Sorry again.

Comment: no worries... unfortunately I'm not that familiar with Python, but I'm not sure I understand how such a JSON is supposed to be saved into an Excel file. It has a complex hierarchy, not just a flat key-value structure. Anyway, I would probably do the following steps: (1) "hardcode" the JSON that fails into a string, and try with it. (2) After it fails - simplify the JSON (basically strip some keys from it), and try again. If it still fails - strip more, until it succeeds. Once it succeeds - start to build back towards the original JSON. Eventually you will figure out the problem..

Comment: @obe Thank you obe. abhikumar22 showed me that I went wrong about converting json file into dictionary. I should study pd and json reference more. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code as well, it is working fine

```
URL = "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json?limit=3&offset=0&createdBefore=1573862400"

// fetching the json response from the URL
req = requests.get(URL)
text_data= req.text
json_dict= json.loads(text_data)

//converting json dictionary to python dataframe for results object
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict["results"])
```

Finally, saving the dataframe to excel format i.e ***xlsx***

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Oh my. So What was wrong about my try was that I didn't convert json into dictionary correctly, right?
Thank you for the help with footnotes! You are my lifesaver. Thank you!

Comment: yeah certainly. that's the issue. you can upvote it if it helps. Thanks :)